# How can i find immediate repeat of any char?

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I want my program to find all immediate repeat of any char.**For example if input is "APAMMANNA"**, i want the program to count immediate repeated char as many time it appears. so **output should be "2"** for given example.

I have written this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char input[51];

    int n, i, count=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&input[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==input[i+1]);
            count++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

But i this program seems not working, Can anyone tell me why this program cann't compare following condition?

> if(input[i]==input[i+1]);

So, can anyone help me to find out where i am going wrong?

Comment: What should the output of "ABABBABBBABBBBA" be? And what about "ABBBAAAA"?

Comment: And for starters, add a `printf("%s\n", input);` to see what the actual content is.

Comment: You're going to run off the end of the string with the "i+1" when i==(n-1)  AND you haven't defined the last entry.
Further, you DONT want the ";" after the "if" !

Comment: @Broman they can't print out `input` as it's not a `NUL` terminated string

Comment: @ChrisTurner Well, just modify the print statement to a finite length. Anyhow, it's basic debugging.

Comment: Here 6 should be output for "ABAB**B**AB**BB**AB**BBB**A" and 5 for "AB**BB**A**AAA**".i marked those repeated char as bold, hope u can understand my problem@Broman

Comment: and `AABBBAAC`?

Comment: only immediate repeat of any char. and answer for your example would be A**A**B**BB**A**A**C, so 4.However i got it bro.made stupid mistake @vlad_tepesch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here

```
if(input[i]==input[i+1]);
    count++;
```

This always increases the `count`. This is because of that semicolon. Instead, it should be:

```
if(input[i]==input[i+1])
    count++;
```

The reason why it didn't work is because with the semicolon, the semicolon (which does nothing) is the entire body of the `if` statement. That's why the count is always increased as the `count++;` is not part of the `if`.

> For example if input is "APAMMANNA"

Actually, it needs to be something like "10 APAMMANNA" because you're reading in `n` first, and even then, it's a bit ugly because the space after the number will be part of your string.

Comment: Forgot to write the first input in example which is int,thanks for help though.I can understand now,where i was making mistake.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, avoid `scanf` and use `fgets` instead when storing strings. I don't understand why you're asking for the length of the string, you can obtain it with `strlen`. There is also an extra semicolon after your `if` statement which will make the `count++` not part of the statement and therefore, will always be executed (even if the statement is false).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[51];
    int n, i, count=0;

    fgets(input,51,stdin);
    n=strlen(input);

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==input[i+1]) 
            count++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```